# I need to start using Versioning and Source Control

Tags: php, mysql, version-control

I'm a PHP/MySQL developer who hasn't used any form of versioning aside from copy/paste into a backup folder. I develop in a Windows environment as well. Where should I go, and what should I do to start using Versioning and Control software?

I'm curious, do these methods also apply to the databases you're using and their schema's?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subversion.  Its solid, and you can use TortoiseSVN as a client in windows (if you're on windows).  Eclipse also has good subversion support.

I don't know enough about database question but at a minimum you could have versioned sql exports.

EDIT: Subversion, and TortoiseSVN are free :-)

There's a similar linux 'port'of TortoiseSVN called Subdiversvn but I haven't used it that much

Comment: Make sure you understand the limitations of Subversion's branch support before you jump in head first.

Comment: In my experience, Subversion's branch support in 1.5 and above is actually pretty good (although I don't have much experience with alternatives to compare).

Comment: But don't forget. He'll also have to setup his Subversion repository. (A task that's beyond the scope of those client tools.)

Comment: Which Subversion plugin do you recommend for Eclipse?

Comment: @Nate - Creating a local Subversion repository with TortoiseSVN is as simple as right-click, TortoiseSVN, Create repository here.

Comment: @Nate - Pretty sure Versions supports creating local repositories from within the app too :-)

Answer (score 3):

I you are the only one working on the source I would recommend using git or mercurial. Unlike SVN, there is no need to set up a server. If you are developing on windows, I would recommend mercurial with TortoiseHg.

Comment: though I've never used these, I've heard of them.  The only problem I would forsee with not setting up a server is that you don't have offsite backups as such. Does that sound right?

Comment: there's no need to set up a server with svn either - you can use file: URLs

Comment: That is definitely a problem with keeping the repository local-only. You can use git to work locally and then eventually push your changes to a remote repository at your leisure. I use SVN at work and I like them both.

Comment: @David, as MattC mentioned, with git and mercurial, there is an option to push source to a server. So it can be backed up off site.

@kdgregory - I wasn't aware that was an option with SVN. Are there any drawbacks to using SVN way?

Comment: @epotter - not that I know of, although it's definitely not something that I'd want to do with a team, due to possible permissions problems. I just run *svnserve* in daemon mode, even for my "team of one." Also, it's possible that the file: URL won't work with a DB-backed repository, but again, for personal use I'd go with a file-backed repo (and reading between the lines, it seems the SVN people would as well).

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to source control I would start by reading about the [basic concepts](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) first.

Comment: +1  -- I am in the same position as Jonathan, but with less work experience.  The article is going to get me from the "60,000-ft view" to something like ground level, which is always the first big step forward.  (Last week I made my first Selenium tests through Firefox browser!)

Answer (score 2):

My personal tool of choice for Windows is [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), which is a GUI front-end to Subversion. You can also use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) if you have nothing against command-line interfaces (or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows) for Git GUIs).

As for database versioning, I use my own tool called [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby) - it supports pretty much everything I need, including native SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are developing and where/how you develop. If you are developing stuff and constantly on the move I would use a distributed source control like [GIT](http://www.git-scm.org/)/Mercurial or if you are always developing them from the same place and can always access your repository then I would recommend [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Subversion (SVN) is probably the only source versioning control software you will ever need to know. TortoiseSVN is a nice client for Windows.

For database schema, what I normally do is to create a sub-folder called "db" and put all my schema there. Be it MySQL, Oracle, MsSQL, etc. I then check the folder into SVN.

You would probably want to have schema upgrade scripts in that folder too.

Answer (score 0):

If I were starting fresh I would look at one of the newer generation of distributed version tools like mercurial, git, or bazaar. [Here is a decent write](http://www.russellbeattie.com/blog/distributed-revision-control-systems-git-vs-mercurial-vs-svn) up of git vs mercurial vs svn.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto on the TortoiseSVN with Subversion.  I would also suggest using a hosted SVN repository like [google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) or [xp-dev](http://xp-dev.com).

Answer (score 0):

I've switched from Subversion to Git.  Branches are important to me and Git's branch support is unmatched.  I use the Windows GUI mostly and the command line occasionally.

Also, it definitely applies to database schemas.  Keep all your DDL changes as text files and version them.  I used to work on a large Sybase database that the DBA's couldn't reproduce without restoring from a backup tape and cleaning out the tables. They didn't have the DDL to create the DB from scratch and even if they did (there are several tools that could generate it) they weren't setup to handle versioning anyway.

Comment: Which GUI do you use? I'm loving Git on Ubuntu, but it's hard to coerce my Windows colleagues...

Comment: @Dean - I started with Git GUI but am moving to Git Extentions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thorough and accessible blog post on the [process of using Subversion in a development workflow](http://blog.athleticsnyc.com/on-using-subversion-for-web-projects).

As for setting up your repository and handling deployments, you might try a Subversion Hosting service like [Springloops](http://www.springloops.com) or [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/). Those make the process a piece of cake. Here's a thorough sortable [list of Subversion Hosts](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/).